# Associate Contacts to Products/Contracts - Dynamics CRM

Tags: c#, powershell, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm new to Dynamics CRM 2013 SDK and using it with powershell, i managed to create new contact, associate it to account, update and such,

however i can't find how to associate/link a contact to a contracts/products, or the opposite way add contact as a contract/product members,

here's for example my code:

```
## Create a contact

$Contact = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity -ArgumentList "contact"
$Contact["fullname"] = "demo-contact"
$Contact["emailaddress1"] = "contact@demo.com"

$id = $service.Create($Contact);

## Associate Contact to Account(Customer)

$accountToUpdate = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity -ArgumentList "contact"
$accountToUpdate.Id = $id;
$Customer = $Account.ToEntityReference()
$accountToUpdate["parentcustomerid"] = $Customer
$service.Update($accountToUpdate)
```

Now, what are the steps to associate it to a product/contract?
[Powershell code is preferable, if possible]

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to accomplish this via powershell vs plugin (c#)?  It's not that powershell cant be used, but people that know both powershell and the CRM sdk are quite rare, so getting a good answer here could be tough.

Comment: if not powershell then c# will be ok, i will convert it somehow, it's .net after all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you need in c#. If you have custom relationships that you want to use, you would just set whatever the relationship schema name is into that Relationship object.

```
// Create an object that defines the relationship between the contact and contract.
Relationship relationship = new Relationship("contract_customer_contacts");

//Set up the EntityReferenceCollection that you are associating the contact to
EntityReferenceCollection contractRefs = new EntityReferenceCollection().Add(
    new EntityReference(Contract.EntityLogicalName, _contractId));

//Associate the contact with the contract(s).
_service.Associate(Contact.EntityLogicalName, _contactId, relationship,
contractRefs);
```